# Where does the potential energy go?

Tags: magnetic-fields, energy-conservation, atomic-physics, magnetic-moment

For a particle with a magnetic moment to be trapped by a magnetic field, kinetic energy must be exchanged for potential energy.

Imagine the scenario where a particle is trapped within a quadrupole magnetic field, i.e. the field magnitude increases linearly outwards from the origin, and the potential experienced is proportional to the field magnitude. At some point, the particle will exchange all (or a proportion) of its kinetic energy for potential energy such that it sits at some high field magnitude region. Now, if the field is suddenly switched off, the particle will remain at rest. However, where does the potential energy go?

This scenario is quite similar to a technique used in atomic-physics experiments using trapped neutral atoms with magnetic moments. The technique is used to measure the temperature of a cloud of atoms from the ballistic expansion of the gas after suddenly switching the magnetic confining field off.

My initial thinking is that when the particle is at this high field region, a maximum force is being applied to it and to the structure generating the field, such that, when the fields are removed, the potential energy lost is converted into kinetic energy of the structure?

Comment: Well,to be exact,  this is if you want the trapped particle to be at rest.  You could trap a particle which continues to 'orbit' with constant KE but doesn't escape.